# Objective-C: UIApplicationMain fourth parameter

Tags: iphone, objective-c, delegates

For the UIApplicationMain function in main(), can anyone tell me the difference between specifying `nil` for the fourth parameter (the delegate class name) and specifying `NSStringFromClass([AppDelegate class])`, as I have seen in some codes?

Apple documentation says to specify nil if the app delegate object is situated in the main nib file, so why would one use the `NSStringFromClass` function for the parameter?

Kind regards.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you said, when you pass nil to 4th parameters of UIApplicationMain(), it will need `MainWindow.xib`. And you can see this [apple official sample codes](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/StreetScroller/Listings/StreetScroller_main_m.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40011102-StreetScroller_main_m-DontLinkElementID_10), it has no `MainWindow.xib`, and it decides its xib layout for iPhone or iPad in runtime.

Answer (score 0):

One possible difference is yo have to last argument as string when you are not using MainWidow.xib. Or i can say when you are are creating all the views,controller and window programatically. Thus this last argument will register particular class as app delegate.

This is done in main window XIB other wise.

This is not all but hope it helps....